# Spring XML, isn't really a way to use angle brackets or backslash codes in string values?

Tags: java, spring

I'm having hard time trying to define a string in Spring that contains an HTML template, i.e., something like the following, which instead is not accepted by Spring:

```
<bean class = "com.example.View">
  <property name = "header">
    <![CDATA[<p>
\t<h1>An example of header</h1>
\t<hr/>
    </p>]]>
</property>
```

This is normally possible in XML, CDATA allows one to tell the parser what is to be ignored. However, I cannot find anything in Spring XML to define a constant value as a text node, rather than as content of the 'value' attribute (their XSD has a '' tag, but it's not for this purpose). Moreover, I'd like strings interpreted the Java way, ie, '\t' to be translated into tab.

I've read other answers suggesting to XML-quote characters like <> (ie, using '<>'), but that's simply impractical in cases like the above and I can't believe there isn't a simpler solution. Note that I already know I could simply send that HTML to a separated file and use some static method to read the latter into a string, but I'm considering the case where I have many of those fragments and I want them together with the Spring bean configuration.

Comment: So you want a literal but it should still be interpreted?! that is weird. imho you should use a regular tab instead of `\t`. Also how is it failing? If there is an exception post it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I want it interpreted as a Java string, but that is the easy part, because I guess I could use SpEL and unescape functions from the Apache Commons library (regular tabs might be another option, though I'd like to support Java style strings). The problem is with the angle brackets, the XML parser doesn't want them in attributes, complaining just that, and the CDATA syntax above doesn't comply with the XSD for Spring XML (so, I get a mismatch error from the schema validator).

Comment: I still don't see what would be wrong with this as I used that in many projects for many years (currently mainly using java). So please again add the error you get to your post.

Comment: @M.Deinum, wow, now it works perfectly (apart from the \t, but this is less important). Don't know how before it was telling me something like <value> not valid under <property>

Answer (score 0):

OK, as suggested by @M.Deinum in the comments (many thanks again), the solution is simply to use `<value>` + `CDATA`:

```
<property name = "header">
  <value><![CDATA[  Just a <b>test</b> value.}]]></value>
</property>
```

Which I had initially tried, but for some reason I cannot reproduce, Spring (namely, the XML validation of their schema) was complaining that `<value>` is not valid in that place.

This allows for writing things like \t directly, i.e., by just pressing tab while editing the file. But the case where one wants to explicitly say '\t' can be managed combining SpEL and Apache commons:

```
<property name = "header">
  <value><![CDATA[#{T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils).unescapeJava (
                "\tJust a <b>test</b> value."
  )}]]></value>
</property>
```

A bit ugly, but works.